# merge empty array on javscript with current array inorder to remvove the current items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I trying to find a nice way to handle merging array and update state depends on the array that comes from the server, the array could be empty - meaning remove all value from the state )one by one).

my goal is to update a new state depends on the array  and send "remove/add" actions
for example on react-redux

I have a subscription in redux action that got an array every 1 second with a "warning list" and I need to update the store accordingly

my question is how do I achieve this "merge" in an efficient way.

I tried with concat() and spread operator but this is kind of classic merge

```
Arr1 ( from server) = []
arr2 = [{"id":1},{"id":2"}]

result : []
actions: = remove id 1 , remove id 2
-----------------------------------
 Arr1 = [{"id:1}]
 arr2 = [{"id":1},{"id":2"}]

result : [{"id":1}]
actions: = remove id 2  , add id 1

--------------------------------------

Arr1 = [{"id":1}]
arr2 = []

result : [{"id":1}]

actions: =  add id:1
```

I would like to manually send "add warning" and "remove warning" actions to redux ( for now is not possible to send those events one by one from the server),

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @KarthickVinod updated my question, basically, I want to achieve in an efficient way the example above

Comment: Why do you want to concat in first place? Why don't directly use array comming from server? All your result is same as array coming from server

Comment: @Kenny I would like to manually send "add warning" and "remove warning" actions to redux ( for now is not possible to send those events one by one from the server), and if I will update all array directly  it will be kind of mess

Comment: Given that `{x:1}` does not equal `{x:1}` because `({x:1}!=={x:1})===true`, how do you want to detect objects in arr1 to be in arr2. Is there a unique id in the objects that you can compare?

Comment: @HMR sorry based on Id . updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example app that you may find useful, there is not much comments but please let me know if you need any help. Here is the sample app:

```js
//imports (does not work for snippet)
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector, defaultMemoize } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  current: [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
  ],
  messages: [],
};
//action types
const SET_CURRENT = 'SET_CURRENT';
const SET_NEXT = 'SET_NEXT';
const REMOVED = 'REMOVED';
const ADDED = 'ADDED';
const CLEAR_MESSAGES = 'CLEAR_MESSAGES';
//action creators
const setCurrent = (val) => ({
  type: SET_CURRENT,
  payload: JSON.parse(val),
});
const setNext = (val) => ({
  type: SET_NEXT,
  payload: JSON.parse(val),
});
const removed = (id) => ({
  type: REMOVED,
  payload: id,
});
const added = (id) => ({
  type: ADDED,
  payload: id,
});
const clearMessages = () => ({
  type: CLEAR_MESSAGES,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === SET_CURRENT) {
    return {
      ...state,
      current: payload,
    };
  }
  if (type === REMOVED || type === ADDED) {
    return {
      ...state,
      messages: state.messages.concat(`${type} ${payload}`),
    };
  }
  if (type === CLEAR_MESSAGES) {
    return {
      ...state,
      messages: [],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const createMemArray = () => {
  const mem = defaultMemoize((...array) => array);
  return (array) => mem.apply(undefined, array);
};
const selectCurrent = (state) => state.current;
const selectMessages = (state) => state.messages;
const selectCurrentIds = ((memArray) =>
  createSelector([selectCurrent], (current) =>
    memArray(current.map(({ id }) => id))
  ))(createMemArray());
//get missing and added when comparing next to current
const selectDiff = ((memArray) =>
  createSelector(
    [
      selectCurrentIds,
      (_, next) => memArray(next.map(({ id }) => id)),
    ],
    (currentIds, next) => {
      const added = next.filter(
        (n) => !currentIds.includes(n)
      );
      const missing = currentIds.filter(
        (c) => !next.includes(c)
      );
      return [added, missing];
    }
  ))(createMemArray());
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //middleware handling SET_NEXT action will
      //  dispatch removed and added for each item that
      //  has been removed or added
      ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
        if (action.type === SET_NEXT) {
          dispatch(clearMessages());
          const [extra, missing] = selectDiff(
            getState(),
            action.payload
          );
          missing.forEach((id) => dispatch(removed(id)));
          extra.forEach((id) => dispatch(added(id)));
          return; //do not let reducer handle SET_NEXT
        }
        return next(action);
      }
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const current = useSelector(selectCurrent);
  const messages = useSelector(selectMessages);
  const [currentVal, setCurrentVal] = React.useState(
    JSON.stringify(current, undefined, 2)
  );
  const [nextVal, setNextVal] = React.useState(
    '[{"id":2},{"id":3}]'
  );
  const onChange = (e) => setCurrentVal(e.target.value);
  const onChangeNext = (e) => setNextVal(e.target.value);
  const saveCurrent = () =>
    dispatch(setCurrent(currentVal));
  const saveNext = () => dispatch(setNext(nextVal));
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>current</h2>
        <div>
          <textarea
            value={currentVal}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={saveCurrent}>Set current</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>next</h2>
        <div>
          <textarea
            value={nextVal}
            onChange={onChangeNext}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={saveNext}>Set next</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>messages</h3>
        <ul>
          {messages.map((m) => (
            <li key={m}>{m}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: HI , what does defaultMemoize?

Comment: Great job thanks , i thinks its over kill. i would like to create a bridge that will got the array from server , got the current array from store . merge , and then will dispach "ADD" or "`Remove"

Comment: @Tuz Diff code is already posted by ipinlnd and in the selectDiff selector function of my code. The defaultMemoize is used here to not create a new array when you do `[{id:1}].map(({id})=>id)` it remembers that the outcome was `[1]` so when the next time the outcome is `[1]` again it won't re create the array. This will prevent unneeded re renders in React. See [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) for information about using selectors (not having the optimised array memoization yet).

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually merging anything here. You're simply setting the server array to the local array, and then sending some messages based on the difference.
My idea would be to do 2 n^2 searches, once for the removed items and another for the added.

```
// Removed
arr2.forEach(item => {
  if (Arr1.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id) === -1) {
    // send the message for the removed item
  }
})

// Added
Arr1.forEach(item => {
  if (arr2.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id) === -1) {
    // Send the message for the added item
  }
})

// Update the local array
arr2 = Arr1.slice(0);
```